# r : pivot tibble multiple columns

Tags: r, pivot

I would like to pivot following tibble1 to make tibble2.

tibble1

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~SUBJID, ~ARM, ~TIMEPOINT,     ~TP.DATE,     ~TPR_ar,
  2610003,  "B",      "BL0", "2019-03-26", "Undefined",
  2610003,  "B",      "FU1", "2019-05-30",        "SD",
  2610003,  "B",      "FU2", "2019-08-05",        "SD",
  2610003,  "B",      "FU3", "2019-10-04",        "SD",
  2610003,  "B",      "FU4", "2019-12-04",        "NE",
  2610003,  "B",      "FU5", "2020-02-07",        "SD",
  2610003,  "B",      "FU6", "2020-04-14",        "SD",
  2610003,  "B",      "FU7", "2020-07-07",        "SD",
  2610004,  "C",      "BL0", "2019-03-26", "Undefined",
  2610004,  "C",      "FU1", "2019-06-11",        "SD",
  2610004,  "C",      "FU2", "2019-07-29",        "NE",
  2610004,  "C",      "FU3", "2019-08-20",        "PD"
  )
```

tibble2

```
tibble::tribble(
   ~SUBJID, ~ARM,         ~BL0,         ~FU1,         ~FU2,         ~FU3,         ~FU4,         ~FU5,         ~FU6,         ~FU7,
  2610003L,  "B", "03/26/2019", "05/30/2019", "08/05/2019", "10/04/2019", "12/04/2019", "02/07/2020", "04/14/2020", "07/07/2020",
  2610003L,  "B",  "Undefined",         "SD",         "SD",         "SD",         "NE",         "SD",         "SD",         "SD",
  2610004L,  "C", "03/26/2019", "06/11/2019", "07/29/2019", "08/20/2019",           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,
  2610003L,  "C",  "Undefined",         "SD",         "NE",         "PD",           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA
  )
```

So far, I've tried

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c('TIMEPOINT'), values_from = c('TP.DATE','TPR_ar'))
```

But I didn't get the result I wanted.
Your help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make `TP.DATE` and `TPR_ar` into one single variable, then you can pivot by `TIMEPOINT`, using them as the variable to fill the values.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

tibble1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("TP")) %>% 
  select.list(-name) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = TIMEPOINT,values_from = value)
```